# Can someone explain how to make this question clearer?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions

[This question seems extremely clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836915/how-do-we-spawn-different-characters-using-happyfuntimes-api-in-unity/). Far clearer than many still open questions.

My only guess is the question is not in most people's domain and so because they don't understand the questions in the domain they're closing it. That seems ludicrous given that most of us don't know every domain. I might have no idea what a monad is. If someone asks a question about monads should I vote to close it because it's unclear to me? Do they need to spell out what a monad is incase someone doesn't understand?

The question referenced above is perfectly clear to anyone with a passing knowledge of the topic. There's a library, referenced in the question. The library lets you use your phone as a controller letting you have locally multiplayer games with 10s or even 100s of people. The question is asking how to let people select a character in the game because none of the samples have that option. This is not the same as doing it in a typical 1-4 player game because in those games that selection happens on the TV/Computer, something you can't do with 100+ players. Similarly it's not the same as a mobile game because in a mobile game that selection happens on the phone and only the phone.

All of that can be added to the question but **NONE OF IT IS RELEVANT TO ANYONE IN THE DOMAIN**. They already know they are making a multi-player game, they already know the player will select on the phone, that selection has to be communicated to the game somehow and the game has to then some how use the correct graphics. The only people confused are people outside the domain. That's no different than my confusion if I saw a question about monads. I wouldn't close the question because I didn't know what a monad was and AFAICT the referenced question shouldn't have been closed either for the same reasons. I wouldn't expect an entire description of what monads are in the question just so people not familiar with monads can understand the question.

Maybe I'm completely missing what's making the quesiton unclear. If so please enlighten me. Otherwise I guess I start voting to close a hell of a lot more question based on this.

Comment: `Selecting characters is a very game specific feature so it's hard to give a specific answer`. Isn't that unclear, or too broad, or opinion?

Comment: Hm.  After your edits, the question is a lot more clear.  But perhaps other users felt it was "too broad"?

Comment: You still need at least one example to get your thoughts going don't you? I'm sure I can find plenty of other questions for which there are 1000s a possible answers. Does that make the question unclear? "[How do you sort an array of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/java-sort-an-array)"? There's about 1000 possible answers to that question. Should it have been closed?

Comment: *"because they don't understand the questions in the domain they're closing it"* - that is not necessarily an accurate assumption, and it's not terribly helpful to make it.

Comment: Yes, please feel free to downvote and VTC questions that specify a requirement without any indication of what the OP tried and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you think the question needs to be clearer, but the final line:

> How would you implement this using HappyFunTimes?

makes it too broad. That makes it so difficult to give a specific answer (as you indicate yourself), and that makes this non-specific question non-appropriate for our Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

> My only guess is the question is not in most people's domain

That's not a guess.  He needs somebody that has HappyFunTimes too.  By tagging it [c#] and [javascript] he's yelling for help in a large stadium full of people that have their own idea what a happy fun time looks like.  And that's not digging through some library they never heard of without any clue whatsoever what he tried.

Using those tags is okay if he's willing the spend the time to get the visitors at least a little bit up to speed.  SO users never mind learning something new.  He just didn't take the time.

I removed those tags.